# MP280 print to scale

Tags: printing

Can I get my MP280 printer to print to scale? I am wanting to print patterns and at the moment an inch in measurement prints out one centimetre or so short of a full one inch.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: In the printer settings there should be an option for that, saying something like “shrink page if necessary to fit borders”.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux `lp` command is basic command to printing a file . You can check `-o` option for customize printing ( Page type , layout , ... ) .

See `man lp` and `man lpadmin` for getting know about options also check following link for examples : [lp examples](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulp.htm)